# Handle post attachments Facebook API SDK 4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, handle, facebook-sdk-4.0

Friend, I can not handle the data that return the call. How can I interact with the data, specifically with attachments. the complete result of calling this the link: http://pastebin.com/fLjV0Zu2

I'm using the conversion method for array, but it seems that this method does not interact at all levels of the object. So I can not reach the data attachments to handle.

```
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

$media = $graphObject->getProperty('attachments')->asArray();
print_r($media);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [subattachments] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [media] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [image] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [height] => 483
                                                [src] => https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10891987_811524088885970_7055896286836804482_n.jpg?oh=895cce48d5da3e59b374fad2f7ec8f69&oe=55297847
                                                [width] => 720
                                            )

                                    )

                                [target] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 811524088885970
                                        [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524088885970&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                                    )

                                [type] => photo
                                [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524088885970&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [media] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [image] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [height] => 404
                                                [src] => https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10885099_811524235552622_234704175575422999_n.jpg?oh=d94c5f69852665adb5a8bae2217cc900&oe=552A30F4
                                                [width] => 720
                                            )

                                    )

                                [target] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 811524235552622
                                        [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524235552622&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                                    )

                                [type] => photo
                                [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524235552622&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [media] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [image] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [height] => 404
                                                [src] => https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10898031_811524285552617_7673546158326216312_n.jpg?oh=3376e9140822a7a79904f58f30214c5d&oe=552D6772
                                                [width] => 720
                                            )

                                    )

                                [target] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 811524285552617
                                        [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524285552617&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                                    )

                                [type] => photo
                                [url] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=811524285552617&set=gm.767232516689804&type=1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [target] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 767232516689804
                [url] => https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.767232516689804&type=1
            )

        [title] => Photos from Conceicao Fernandes's post
        [type] => album
        [url] => https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.767232516689804&type=1
    )
```

)

Comment: Why not just use the objects instead. Much better way to handle it anyway

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to interact with objects as you said?

Comment: Like this `$object->subattachments`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I managed doing so.

`$media[0]->subattachments->data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem. Or rather doubt.

The friend WizKid cleared my ideas.

Even using the correct method to convert the result of GraphObject using Facebook PHP SDK4, calling `asArray();` to access the data, I used the form below with success.

```
$media = $graphObject->getProperty('attachments')->asArray();
$media[0]->subattachments->data;
```

To interact with the data I'm using `foreach()`

```
$data = $media[0]->subattachments->data;
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
      //Here you interacted with the data
    }
```